# I have to retrieve data of one table from postgres sql which doesn't exist in another table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 3 tables ,

Table 1 columns- uuid1(unique) ,uuid2(unique)

Table2 columns- uuid1(unique),A,B,C,D

Table 3 columns uuid2(unique),A1,B1,C1

I have to find the data in table 2, which is not present in table 3, table 1 is the mapping table. In other words data which isn't selected when I inner join table 2 and table 3. What's the sql query for the same in postgres? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Probably do an outer join on table 3 via table 1 with a where clause on table3.a1 is null

Comment: Ie select * from table2 t2 left outer join table1 t1 on t1.uuid1 = t2.uuid1 left outer join table3 t3 on t3.uuid2 = t1.uuid2 where T3.a1 is null

Comment: Actually, no need to go to table3 if table 1 is a mapping, just outer join on that where uuid1 or uuid2 is null

Comment: Hi @Chris I think the outer join should work. And we have to go to the table 3 as the data is missing in table3 . Table 1 has all the mapping. For ex. if table 1 has a mapping where uuid 1 is 'aaa' and uuid2 is 'bbb' . Now there's a record of 'aaa' in table2 but no record of 'bbb' in table 3. I need all all the 'bbb' type records. Anyway could you explain the outer join approach once?Thanks

Comment: ^^ adding to this , I need the 'aaa' record from table 2(meaning this record is missing in table 3)

Comment: Hi sanchit, I'd hope that there is no mapping in table 1 if there is no data in table 3, ideally table 1 would have foreign key constraints so that the data you describe could not exist. Anyway, whether you have to go to table 3 or not, you could use outer join with null check or not exists clause as specified in the answer from Tim. It would be interesting to look at an explain plan to see if the DBMS executes them the same way. Outer join just means that every row in the first table is returned even if there is no joining row in the other, and it can be applied over many joins

Comment: From a maintainability perspective I think Tim's approach is easier to understand, so I'd be inclined to go with that. If you did have to go to table 3 (and I'm sure that can't be the case) then just select from table 2 join on table 1 uuid1 where not exists (select from table 3 where uuid2 = table1.uuid) (pseudo code)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a basic exists query should work here:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.uuid1 = t2.uuid1);
```

Note that we don't even need to involve `Table3` here, because the `Table1` mapping table ideally should represent every value from `Table3` which maps to something in `Table2`.